# Computing Norm of Matrix Operator (part b confusion)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the norm $||x||_p=\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\, |x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. Let T be a matrix operator:$T =
\begin{pmatrix}
a &
b \\
c &
d \\
\end{pmatrix}$ mapping ($\mathbb{R^2},||x||_p)$ into ($\mathbb{R^2},||x||_p)$.

a. Compute $||T||$ when $b=c$ and $p=2$.

b. Compute $||T||$ in general.

My Attempt:

Here is my attempt:

a. I now understand the definition of operator norm and induced matrix norm. I have figured out the answer for part a:
The answer should be the maximum eigenvalue of :$
\begin{pmatrix}
a &
b \\
b &
d \\
\end{pmatrix}$  *$
\begin{pmatrix}
a &
b \\
b &
d \\
\end{pmatrix}$ .

which can be easily computed.
b. I'm not sure about part b., however, so any help would be much much appreciated for this part (part b).  I understand that there is a simple way of computing the operator norm or induced matrix norm when $p=1$, $p=2$ or when $p=\infty$. However, it is unclear to me what it means to compute $||T||$ in general.  I'm not sure if this turns into a lagrange multipliers question using the definition of operator norm, which is:

[image]

Thank you very much. The bounty is placed/will be accepted for help on part b.

Comment: How are you getting those expressions for $\|T\|$?

Comment: Hi @WillJagy, I was not given/had not learned about matrix norms induced by vector norms. So does that mean the answer for part a.) is the maximum absolute row sum?

Comment: I'm not sure how to how to express this in terms of a, b, and d.  Does this mean, the answer is ||T||=max{(a+b),(b+d)}.  A little confused thanks.

Comment: It is from Naylor and Sell Linear Operator Theory Section 5.8

Comment: @WillJagy  How do I compute eigenvalues in this case if I don't have numbers, just a,b,and d? Thanks.

Comment: @Y.Forman I just squared the entries, added them together and took the square root.  I'm not sure if this is right though.

Comment: You should have some notion of the norm of an operator.

Comment: @Y.Forman I'm not sure what it means to be a norm of an operator.

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, so I can't tell you where to look. But I strongly suspect you have missed this definition. After all, the question defines $T$ as a matrix operator, and then asks you about its norm -- so you must have some notion of the norm of a matrix operator before making any sense out of this question!